# Pass object id from template to form on next template

Tags: python, django

I have a post detail page for coding challenges at url /codingchallenges/int:pk, and within this page is a button for users to make a submission. This button takes them to /submission/new which is a form for the submission model. How can I pass the post id of the coding challenge into the submission form?

Comment: Add post_id as a parameter to the url? `/submission/new/<int:post_id>/`

Comment: Can you please provide some sample code of what you have so far.

Comment: I had it as a parameter to the url as you stated, it worked fine, but how can I then pass that value into the form? The submission model uses a coding challenge as a foreign key, and at the moment the form for the submission has a charfield for the user to select a coding challenge. I want to automatically set that charfield value